# No ONE Here to help me !... Frustated about Different Size but same result when rendered

Tags: java, android, image, opengl-es, textures

Update : I am sorry, i earned tumbleweed badge before, and this thread also has been quiet for a whole day...

I am editing whole my question as it might not so clear for others to help.

[Take a look at this game image](http://www.bloggerkilat.com/?p=357)

I am modifying super jumper game (Mario Zechner's Beginning Android Game) , i've come to stuck in this issue:

if you look at my image link above, you could see that my character image rendered in same size with the spring image.

i'm using texture atlas 1024x1024 px,

```
      spring = new TextureRegion(items, 980, 90, 32, 40);
      charJump = new Animation(0.2f,
          new TextureRegion(items,charX+32, charY, 64,160),
          new TextureRegion(items, charX+150, charY, 64, 160)); //char anim.
```

I am using photoshop and put all the texture region required in my Atlas. 
For each character image frame has the size of 64x150 
while the spring image only has the size of 30x40

the world class camera width and height  = 11f x 14f
the world renderer class camera width and height also  = 11f x 14f

Please give me some clue, what important knowledge i am missing here ?  thank you.

Comment: So the issue is that the character object is drawn as too small and should be twice the size of the spring object in both width and height?

Comment: So I have no idea how the rest of your code works but the texture region should in general not effect the size of the object being drawn. You may for some reason (such as anticipating different resolutions) have a much larger textures then actually needed and then set the appropriate region coordinates. All this still has nothing to do with the actual size of the object being drawn. Your issue is most likely in some other part of your application.

Comment: I Found the culprit !!..  batcher.drawSprite(world.char.position.x, world.char.position.y, side * 1, 1, keyFrame);  , the batcher draw in 1x1 metres(World Coordinate) width and height... OMG.. i am such a fool not to look at my rendering code. Thanks Matic, you're the one here to share your time helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the culprit !!.. batcher.drawSprite(world.char.position.x, world.char.position.y, side * 1, 1, keyFrame); , the batcher draw in 1x1 metres(World Coordinate) width and height... OMG.. i am such a fool not to look at my rendering code. Thanks Matic, you're the one here to share your time helping me out.